# Should we edit "hi", "thanks", salutation from posts

Tags: discussion, tags

It has been a general concensus on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that "hi","thanks" and salutations should be edited from posts.

Should we do the same here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, salutations will tend to be removed, as this is something that has been discussed in a few places, Meta.SO [being one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/168476).

One of the Meta.SO posts sums it up well, saying that:

> If this is supposed to be a website which is servicing more than just
>   the primary author, we need to think about how we construct messages
>   so that they appear more clearly to those searching on google for
>   questions that match their own. If I am looking for a solution for
>   question X, I want to find someone who had the same problem, not their
>   short autobiography and formalities before getting to that actual
>   question.

There are also scripts on Stack Overflow that actually remove such things from questions and so on at the time of submission, but it looks to be only implemented there, if it still is.

It is important to remember, though, that while you are editing out salutations and other related things from posts, check the rest of the post. Is there anything else you could edit to make it better? Fix tags, or edit for grammar or spelling or clarity or any other thing you can think of. :)

Comment: +1. I don't think those scripts still exist on SO because I have seen various posts like that on SO

Comment: I tend to remove them when editing a question or answer.

Comment: Definitely worth reiterating the 'fix all you can' part of this answer. As an anecdote, many 'edit wars' I've seen on the network come from people insisting on putting these back in (rolling back) after they're removed. Don't get in an edit war over 'thanks' - that's just ironic. Flag for one of our fabulous moderator critters instead and let them have a look.

Answer (score 4):

If that is the only edit to be made then generally no. Edits should improve the question, the removal of hi, thanks, etc from a question by itself really does not really do that. If you are going to edit there are generally other edits that should be made to a question.  Fix spelling/grammar errors, add/remove tags, fix wording to be more readable, clarify a title, etc.  If you are in editing for those thing then yes remove the extraneous bits.

If those bits do detract from the question, ie "Hi Sucka's", or something similarly drool by all means help save the OP from themselves.  Though I suspect in those cases that there are other things that you should be cleaning up too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only from questions, and if there are other problems with the question, those should be cleaned up as well at the same time.

Comment: I generally remove them from answers too. A "hello bob", while only 9 characters, takes up the line it's on as well as most likely a blank line or two below it, which pushes other stuff off the screen. If the hello or thank you is in the same line and not separated as an official greeting, then I'll possibly overlook it and pretend I don't see it. :)  My decision is based entirely on how much content is removed from the screen based on the hello or thanks. In the end, SE isn't a forum, and we shouldn't treat it like one. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm mostly referring to a "good luck" here and there.